# Concatenate more than one Infixes in Quill SQL

Tags: sql, where-clause, infix-notation, quill.io

I have to write plain SQL queries inside infixes.
I have a main SQL query and then add AND clauses into it based on certain conditions.

For example :

```
  val andClause= quote { (name: String) =>
    infix"""AND name = $name """.as[Query[(Int, String)]]
   }

   val rawQuery = quote { (id: String, name: String) =>
    infix"""SELECT id, name FROM my_entity WHERE id = $id ${andClause(name)}"""
        .as[Query[(Int, String)]]
  }

 ctx.translate(rawQuery("ramakrishna", "rk”))
```

and this prints

```
  SELECT x._1, x._2 FROM (SELECT id, name FROM my_entity WHERE id = 'ramakrishna' AND name = 'rk' ) AS x
```

as expected.

However I need to concat the infixes conditionally like

```
    val andClause1= quote { (name: String) =>
     infix"""AND name = $name """.as[Query[(Int, String)]]
    }

    val andClause2= quote { (name: String) =>
     infix"""   """.as[Query[(Int, String)]]
    }


   def andClauseCondition(i: String) =
      if (!i.isEmpty) {
         andClause1(i)
   } else {
       andClause2(i)
   }
```

And I am calling my query as

```
val rawQuery = quote { (id: String, name: String) =>
     infix"""SELECT id, name FROM my_entity WHERE id = $id ${andClauseCondition(name)}"""
         .as[Query[(Int, String)]]
   }
```

But I get error as

```
 Error:(231, 26) Tree 'andClauseCondition(name)' can't be parsed to 'Ast'
    val rawQuery = quote { (id: String, name: String) =>
```

Is it possible to append one or more infixes to base query ? If yes, is it the correct way to append ?

Comment: Please format the code in the question and try to minimize your question. Cheers!

Comment: sorry about the wrongly formatted code, the same has been done now, thanks